# Is there any language where stress can be comprised of diminished expiratory force?

Tags: phonetics, resource-request

I can swear I read an online article that gave a resouding yes to that question but I've lost it and my memory is uhm, not the best so I'd like a confirmation.

Comment: Do you mean the airflow is diminished during the stress compared to other syllables?

Comment: Yes, @Nardog. I know it's a little strange but I'm 100% sure I've read this article. I even remember it cited Ladefoged to point out that, in his definition of stress, he didn't mention the possibility of the prosodic change occurring inversely.